# ERROR: Call to a member function paginate() on array

Tags: php, laravel

La consulta si sale en la base lo que no me sale ya es en la parte de la paginate(); me sale de error Call to a member function paginate() on array

```
$usuario=DB::select('select a.id,cedula, a.name, a.apellido,a.usuario_creo,email, perfil, estado,
 (select b.name from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_creo)as nom_creo,
 (select b.apellido from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_creo)as ape_creo,
(select b.name from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_edito)as nom_edito,
(select b.apellido from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_edito)as ape_edito
from users as a where a.eliminar_usuario=?',["NO_ELIMINADO"])->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar con el siguiente código:

```
$usuario=DB::table('users as a')->select('a.id','a.cedula', 'a.name','a.apellido','a.email', 'a.perfil', 'a.estado',
(DB::raw("(select b.name from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_creo)as nom_creo")),
(DB::raw("(select b.apellido from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_creo)as ape_creo")),
(DB::raw("(select b.name from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_edito)as nom_edito")),
(DB::raw("(select b.apellido from users as b where b.id=a.usuario_edito)as ape_edito")))
->where('a.eliminar_usuario','=','NO_ELIMINADO')->paginate(10);
```